# SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate method not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I'm simply trying to implement the iTunes store screen in my application, and it displays correctly. However, when the user is finished with the screen (makes a purchase or clicks 'cancel') all I get is a white screen, and I have to completely close my app and reopen it.

It turns out my `productViewControllerDidFinish` method isn't being called.

I have a table view controller that has the SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate and I'm presenting and dismissing the store view in the same class, so why isn't the delegate method being called?

```
- (void)toStore:(Button*)sender {
    SKStoreProductViewController *storeProductViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    [storeProductViewController loadProductWithParameters:@{SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : @"stuff"} completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@ with User Info %@.", error, [error userInfo]);

        } else {
            [self presentViewController:storeProductViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController*)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Both in a UITableViewController. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate of SKStoreProductViewController controller.. You missed to do that..

Set it just below object allocation..

```
   storeProductViewController.delegate = self;
```